# Why on Finish editing of a DSP from vs code extension XD, not generating CSS, JS etc?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ui-design, adobe-xd

When importing a Design System Package(DSP) (designed in adobe XD) to vscode, after completion of editing expectation is, it generates CSS, JS etc as configured. But instead it is generating json files.
Am I missing any step?

Below are the steps I followed:

1. Created a package in vscode XD extension.
2. Imported a DSP [link](https://assets.adobe.com/public/12e45de1-ef2f-4ec8-6b99-28b1012038a4) into my work repository.
3. Added few code snippets to components.
4. Clicked on **Finish editing**.

And these steps are producing json files in dist/styledictionary/properties folder as

- List item
- colors.json
- custom.json
- fonts.json
- sizes.json

Answer (score 0):

The XD VSCode extension allows you to create shareable Design System Packages (DSPs) that contain all the information developers need to consume while coding, including compiled design tokens, code snippets and design systems documentation. It doesn't generate CSS or JS.

The official post explains it in more detail:
https://www.adobe.com/products/xd/learn/design-systems/cloud-libraries/vscode-extension.html